# How to create subdocument in MongoDB with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to create db stucture (inserting data) via C# with subdocuments. Something similar to picture attached below

Robmongo

[image]

I'm using this way to add "normal" kind of db

```
     var task = collection.InsertOneAsync(new person
           {
                Id = setid,  
                FirstName = name,
                LastName= lastname,
                Email = email,
           });
```

But I have no clue how to add subdocs to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something as below:-

```
 var task = collection.InsertOneAsync(new person
       {
            Id = setid,  
            FirstName = name,
            LastName= lastname,
            Email = email,
            playlists = [ //Array of objects
              {videos:[  //Array of objects
                {
                   title:"1", description:""
                },
                {
                   title:"2", description:""
                }
            ]}
          ]
       });
```